# Angle of twist at D where 2 shaft connected through gears

Tags: strength

So my frind and I find the answer for part A different also chegg says something else. But I can't see whats wrong with my answer. Dont expect you to solve it just show me whats wrong with my answer. Ps. it is homework but due was yesterday for those wonder.

[image: question]

[image: answer]

Comment: What was the solution from Chegg? then we can compare...

Comment: It was begining with saying that torque at B is equal to torque at C. Tb=Tc=20kN.m . After that is simply finding torque at D. But I cant see how Tb=Tc.